# How to add a custom candlestick to highchart stock chart?

Tags: highcharts, candlestick-chart

Using the Candlestick highstock chart,(http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick), I want to have the best last bar a custom candlestick where its available values are High and Low only? This is typical for a forecasting scenario where we would like to predict tomorrow's candlestick would likely to have a certain High (of the day) and Low (of the day). We are not so much concerned about its possible future open or close values. In the end, this (last) candlestick on the chart should look like a Line and not a bar. 
Any idea much appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Use column/columnrange series, with `pointWidth: 1`. Setting example:

```
data: [{
  low: 10, // low
  y: 12,   // high 
  x: date
}]
```

Another solution is to use scatter series with `lineWidth: 1`, for example:

```
data: [{
  y: 10, // low
  x: date
},{
  y: 12, // high
  x: date
}]
```

Comment: The thing is i must use the candlestick chart series and not the others.

Comment: So why don't you just set high and low to the same value as open and close? Candlestick is just candlestick.

Comment: That what I did but I did not think it was a clean solution,.

Comment: For now I don't see any other solution. You can create an idea [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general).

Comment: You can set pointWidth also for candlestick, but thie applies for all series points.